# I'm trying to make a ship command in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to add a function in discord.py that can mention any user with the user that called the command in a discord chat?

```py
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def Ship(ctx):
    await ctx.send(choice(tuple(member.mention for member in ctx.guild.members)))
```

Comment: Congratulations on your attempt, and succes with your attempt to add that function. But, what is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to make a function that says:@user and@user seem nice together

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass in two `member` values.

```py
@client.command()
async def Ship(ctx, user_1 : discord.Member, user_2 : discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"{user_1.mention} and {user_2.mention} seem nice together")
```

Let's say your command prefix is `!`, you would run this like `!Ship <user> <user>`, where you would replace the `<user>` with the username of the people whom you are trying to ship.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate it